# Opencart status update issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, opencart2.x

When I try to update order status in admin panel of order info view it is always updating as cancelled. When I click add history button it is posting order_status but after success it is updating with cancelled status. Actually I want to know the reason why it is happening like this.

Below is Html code,

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-order-status"><?php echo $entry_order_status; ?></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="order_status_id" id="input-order-status" class="form-control">
                      <?php foreach ($order_statuses as $order_statuses) { ?>
                      <?php if ($order_statuses['order_status_id'] == $order_status_id) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $order_statuses['order_status_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $order_statuses['name']; ?></option>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $order_statuses['order_status_id']; ?>"><?php echo $order_statuses['name']; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-notify"><?php echo $entry_notify; ?></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="notify" value="1" id="input-notify" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-comment"><?php echo $entry_comment; ?></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="8" id="input-comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="text-right">
                <button id="button-history" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> <?php echo $button_history_add; ?></button>
              </div>
```

Jquery code,

```
$('#button-history').on('click', function() {
  if(typeof verifyStatusChange == 'function'){
    if(verifyStatusChange() == false){
      return false;
    }else{
      addOrderInfo();
    }
  }else{
    addOrderInfo();
  }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/api&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&api=api/order/history&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'order_status_id=' + encodeURIComponent($('select[name=\'order_status_id\']').val()) + '&notify=' + ($('input[name=\'notify\']').prop('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '&append=' + ($('input[name=\'append\']').prop('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '&comment=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'comment\']').val()),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-history').button('loading');         
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-history').button('reset');   
        },
        success: function(json) {
      alert(json);
            $('.alert').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                $('#history').before('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#history').load('index.php?route=sale/order/history&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>');

                $('#history').before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('textarea[name=\'comment\']').val('');

                $('#order-status').html($('select[name=\'order_status_id\'] option:selected').text());          
            }           
        },          
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug this you will need to step through the controller. Start in the POST section and dump the POST variable to see if the Status ID matches with the ID you wanted.

If they match, you need to follow the logic further and find where it goes next. Is the model getting the right status? Is it updating the database?